# pthread time-out or cancel, using pthread_cond_timedwait, or what?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, delay

I have a thread that waits (blocking) on a message queue for messages to process. *Polling is not an option.*

When a certain **START** message arrives, we set some variable which must then either reset after a given time delay, or be reset by the arrival of another **STOP** message. If it is set, a repeated **START** should extend the set-time by a given time period (could just re-start).

In the meantime, the thread should carry on processing other messages which arrive.

To my mind, the way to do this is spawn and detach a new pthread which will handle the time-out. This thread will either time-out and send a **STOP** message to the parent before exiting, or be killed/cancelled prematurely if a **STOP** message is received by the parent thread.

I've been reading the pthreads documentation and it's not entirely clear to me the best way of doing this:

1. I could create a thread that just sleeps for a given time and then
   sends the **STOP** message, and pthread_cancel() it if a **STOP**
   message arrives sooner. It seems to be implied in the docs (but not explicitly stated) that, in this case, the "cancel" action would basically kill the thread mid-sleep, no further actions.
2. I could create a thread which uses pthread_cond_timedwait() to wait on a condition, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21308756/1389218) example. This looks the most "proper" but also the most cumbersome.
3. Something similar to 1 but fork()ing a process which watches a flag variable and either times out or gives up if the flag is reset.
4. Use SIGALARM handler, plus Alarm() to set / unset a timed signal (sounds simple, but practice seems a bit untidy and you can only have one alarm)

Delays are in the seconds range, accuracy to ~0.1sec would be nice. I'm not keen on the way pthread_cond_timedwait uses an absolute time, as there's a chance the user may set the clock and throw things out of kilter (not the end of the world, but it just seems non-optimal to me).

It's not clear to me from the examples around the net that either "pthread_cancel" or "pthread_cond_timedwait" work / work *cleanly* for a detached thread?

I won't post code of my current favoured option as it would pretty much be a copy-paste of the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21308756/1389218) in option 2.

Comment: Is message queue selectable on your platform? If so, select with the proper timeout seems a viable option.

Comment: I'm not trying to time out if no messages arrive, I'm trying to set a variable that will reset after a time if not otherwise changed. The message queue will be busy with other messages going back & forth in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what you are agonizing over.  As best as I understand your description, timers are plainly the way to go.

- create a timer with `timer_create` to deliver a signal if time elapses.  If all you are doing is setting a switch on variable this is easily done in the signal handler itself
- if you get a STOP message while there is time remaining, disarm the timer with `timer_settime`
- if you get a 2nd START msg while the timer is armed get the time remaining on the timer with `timer_gettime`, add the new amount of time to it, and reset the timer with `timer_settime`.
- delete the timer when you are done with it with timer_delete

Unlike `alarm` or the `itimer` interval timers you are not limited to a single timer.

As an aside, if you are using POSIX message queues and your messages are few and far between it may be worth using `mq_notify`.  Instead of blocking on `mq_receive` all day you can set it to spin up a thread whenever a new message is put in a previously empty queue and you just process any and all messages until the queue is again empty and the thread ends.

Comment: I forgot to add the disclaimer that I'm not very experienced with linux dev, I've been thrown in at the deep end, so wasn't aware of the timer functions. But you're right, they do look a lot like the sort of thing I'm after. R'ing TFM now...

Comment: @John U, if you are on linux or some derivative that supports it, take a look at the `timerfd` facility.  This gives you benefit of using `select` or `poll` to monitor both your signal expiration and (since posix MQ's mqd_t type is a file descriptor on linux) your queue at the same time and not deal with the hassles of handlers.